# how to add custom font in web form visual studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, fonts, visual-studio-2017

[Its a screenshot of the visual studio page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLqtH.png)

I am trying my best to add new custom font i have tried to add the font both n resource folder and font folder but was not successful.

```
   <style type="text/css">
   @font-face{
       font-family:"zekton rg";
       src: url(zekton rg.ttf);
   }

    .auto-style1 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .auto-style2 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .auto-style3 {
        text-align: center;
        height: 33px;
    }
    .auto-style4 {
        height: 33px;
    }
    .auto-style5 {
        height: 39px;
    }
    #Reset1 {
        text-align: left;
        height: 35px;
        width: 72px;
    }
</style>
```

Please help ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because your font hasn't been installed yet.

> Double click the .ttf file.
>   Click the "install" button on top-left.
>   Install the font and try again.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i have double clicked and installed in the font folder but still the problem persist

Comment: Have you tried unzipping or downloading the file again? In case if its corrupted.

Comment: yes but the problem is still there  ...can you tell me what does it mean make sure the application for the file type .ttf is installed ?

Comment: It means your ttf file is not installed properly.

Comment: @font-face 
        {
                font-family: Cubic;
                src: url("C:\Users\gourabkonar\Documents\Visual Studio    2017\Projects\bus_reservation\WebApplication1\fonts\Cubic.ttf");
         }                                   actually there was some problem in detecting path now its working fine thanks for your timely help and suggestion

Answer (score 0):

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=your font name:300,400,400i,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">`

in your head tag

and below line on body tag

```
<body style="font-family: same font name as in url;">
```

Comment: thanks but i have already came to a solution using @font-face